# Can you tell who has joined a Microsoft Teams call before you join it?

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is it possible to find out who is in a meeting before you join it? If for example I don't want to be on the meeting with only one other person? It would be nice to know if they are using video or not so you know whether to join with video.

Comment: Not to my knowledge.

Comment: Never use video. Waste of bandwidth; you already know what your co-workers look like.